# load the functions of a shell script without executing it

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have a shell script which does some functions like making image , downloading tar files,exporting environment variables,download images ...n task etc. I have separate functions for each task. I If I source the shell script it will start running functions one by one. Is there a way to make the functions available to shell without executing it.
Sourcing the shell script will make the function available to shell but it will start executing it.

Actual code:

```
     do_task1();
     #some logging here 
     #shell commands  
     do_task2(); 
     #error checks
     #....
     # there are lot of such things as well as user defined functions.
```

Sourcing this file will actually start executing this since the call to functions exist. I want the user defined functions alone to be available in shell prompt.

One way is to use C style coding ie to have main function which will call other functions. Whenever I want the functions alone to be available in a shell without exec then I could just comment that main call alone. Right now I don't have main function.

```
  function main()
  {
   do_task1();
    #add all the commands and functions here.
   do_task2();
  }
main # I can comment this.
```

Is there any other way(or some shell command)to load the functions alone ?

Why I need this ?
 It will be useful for debugging .
 If I want to run some functions of this shell script I can just run it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most shells (like [bash](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) and [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html)) have support for functions. You can define functions and call them arbitrarily. Sourcing a file with function definitions will not execute them.